# How to stop IntelliJ IDEA from adding extra indentation to multi-line statements?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Bad (what IntelliJ does):

```java
return !enabled ||
    (
        !name.isBlank() &&
            !email.isBlank() &&
            !phone.isBlank()
    );
```

Better (what I want it to do):

```java
return !enabled ||
(
    !name.isBlank() &&
    !email.isBlank() &&
    !phone.isBlank()
);
```

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ IDEA to not add the extra indentation for multi-line boolean statements?

---

I also don't like the formatting when writing HQL (or any multi-line string), e.g.:

Bad:

```java
@Query(
    "SELECT x " +
        "FROM Something x " +
        "WHERE " +
        "blah = 1 AND " +
        "name = 'blah'"
)
```

Good:

```java
@Query(
    "SELECT x " +
    "FROM Something x " +
    "WHERE " +
        "blah = 1 AND " +
        "name = 'blah'"
)
```

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ IDEA to format HQL the way I like it (shown here)?

Answer (score 2):

File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java, Wrapping and Braces, **Binary Expressions**: **Align when multiline**:

[image: Align when multiline]

Comment: You'd think I would have been able to find that ... thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work.... to turn off.

Comment: @mjs Your case is likely different, please post a new question or contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new.

Comment: Yes, it is for multiline strings ... intellij insist on manipulating it